# Cake Addins install fail error during build

Tags: build, teamcity, add-in, cakebuild

I am using net 4.8 framework. and cake version 0.38.2.
During build in Teamcity, it has to install addins cake.npm, cake.filehelpers. But following error happens

```
Could not find any assemblies compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.
Error: Failed to install addin 'Cake.Npm'.
```

When I use cake.npm version as 0.17.0 for cake 0.38.2, it generates two folders - cake.npm and cake.npm0.17.0. Only cake npm0.17.0 is required, because it has netstandard2.0 which can make build successful. But the other folder makes it fail

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Npm/issues/140 `Cake.Npm` is not the culprit, here.
There is an additional (`#load`) reference in the project to `Cake.Sitecore` in version 1.0.3 which in `contents/scripts/tasks.restore.cake` contains the line

```cs
#addin "Cake.Npm"
```

This - without an explicit version being set - will always default to the newest version (currently 2.0.0, which is incompatible with Cake 0.38.2).

The [current version of `Cake.Sitecore` (1.0.27)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Sitecore/1.0.27) has that problem fixed.